# Speed Controller Terminal/Connector?

Tags: motor-controller, speed

I'm kind of confused on what connector (labelled B+, M and B-) this is below:

[image]

[image]

(http://kellycontroller.com/kdz4840024v-48v400aseriespm-p-955.html)
This is a 48V speed controller designed for up to 400A. The connector looks like a spade connector with a screw terminal. I plan on using it with an ME0909 motor Here are my questions

Q1 - I'm planning on buying 2AWG wire and then buying some connector to crimp onto the end of this wire to attach it to B+/B-/M. What appropriate connector do I buy to attach it to the speed controller? What bolt/lug/screw do I need?

Q2 - If it is a screw connector, is there any way of covering it up to prevent shorts? Like is there some special heat shrink or something?

Comment: To me that looks like just a lug & bolt arrangement, meant for big beefy wires. I you're metric then I'd eyeball it at about a M5 bolt (+- 3/16" ?). Heatshrink is probably a very good idea considering the closeness of those terminals to the metal-bodied multi-pin circular connector.

Comment: @brhans I added a side-view to the main post with measurements. I'm having a hard time finding these on sites. Are these screws just standard screws for everything else or are they "special" conducting screws.

Comment: The bolts are really just there to hold the lugs onto the terminals with the right amount of pressure - you shouldn't be relying on them for providing a current path, that's done by the correct amount of pressure being applied (by the bolt) to  the surfaces of the lug and terminal.

Comment: @brhans Ah I understand now. Would 2 AWG be sufficient to carry a continuous current of 100A and a maximum of 300A for no more than 30 seconds (all at 48V). I'm planning on having no more than 2-3m of it.

Comment: You ought to read the manual for motor connections and keep the controller as close to motor as possible and have a heatsink

Answer (score 0):

**You should consult with sales to get the best hardware selection and advice for EMI protection , e.g. twisted pair wire, small loops, fasteners.   Wire type.  The EMI radiated from each wire will be horrendous, so having twisted pairs at right angles reduces coupling.  CM chokes may be necessary as well heatsink and fan.**

A good design will have no more than a 1% drop in voltage at operating current or 1% of the motor DCR winding resistance. (est. ~50 milliohm)

AWG 2 is 0.5127 mOhm/m.  Thus only 1/2 m for a wire pair yelds 1mOhm or 2% loss at startup which is great.

If you use 3m of cable, loss on AWG 2 cable alone is ;

Pd= 3[m] * 2[wires] * 0.5127 [mOhm/m] *  300[A]^2 = 277 Watts  ( No Good)

Therefore if you need 3 m, use AWG 00 12mm dia. cable = 1mOhm (3m*2) = 2% of motor DCR.  Pd = 300^2*1 mOhm= 90 Watts for 30s max or 100A^2*1mOhm = 10W at rated 100A current.

Normally the wire resistance should be much less than the motor's and will rise in temperature with the resistance.

If peak rating is 300A then start current could be as much as 10x the rated current of 100A or a start surge current of 1000A. With 48V this implies a 48mOhm winding resistance (DCR).

Bolts that fit holes,  torqued to proper size crimped silver alloy spade lug with insulated cover such that it is “gas tight fitting”and withstands 50 lb pull test will work.  Any suitable rubber tape insulation will work.  Bolts should be high torque rated automotive type sized to proper length.   You must search for the best method for crimping or bolting the lug to wire with the same high torque. Resistance test  should result in no more than 6 uOhm resistance for 1W dissipation at 400A if you can measure uV to 1mV with some external current source.

Comment: Forgot to mention. The motor can only handle 100A continious and 300A peak for 30 seconds. Would 2 AWG be sufficient for that? I'm planning on having no more than 2-3m of it.

Comment: I meant AWG 2 for 1m but for 3m AWG00.  If you were starting a car in winter with 750CCA you would want the starter cable and battery terminals to be 12mm diameter or so.

Comment: Ah perfect. I think I'll go with AWG00 so just to be safe. I'm not too sure how much wire I'll need. Better to be safe. Just one more thing, any idea how to figure out what hole size is on the controller terminal? the spec sheet doesn't say at all

Comment: It depends how critical loss of starting torque means to your application.

Comment: http://katalog.we-online.de/em/datasheet/5580870.pdf

Comment: With M8? Bolts...

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean by critical loss of starting torque. We're basically making an electric go kart.